# Vue 3 - app.config is undefined. How to bypass this error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm doing everything by the docs, but, still having an error in the console. What I'm trying is to create a global variable of a Firebase instance.

`main.js`:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

import firebase from 'firebase'
require('firebase/firestore')

const config = {
    // config
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)

const app = createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .mount("#app");

console.log(app.config) // undefined
app.config.globalProperties.$firebase = firebase;
```

Why is it `undefined`? Or should I overwrite property `globalProperties` myself in the `config` object?

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`const app = createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount("#app")` returns the **root component instance** not the **app instance** which has the field `config`, so, you should do:

```
const app = createApp(App)

const rootComponent = app.use(store)
  .use(router)
  .mount("#app");

console.log(app.config) 
app.config.globalProperties.$firebase = firebase;
```

Learn more about the differences [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#creating-an-application-instance).

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was having the same exact issue.

Answer (score 8):

`config` exists on the return value of `createApp` instead of the ending `mount` call:

```js
const app = createApp(App);

app.use(store).use(router).mount('#app');

console.log(app.config); // Not undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it in this order

```
    const app = createApp({})
    app.config.globalProperties.DateUtils = DateUtils

    app.use(createVuetify({
        components: components,
        directives: directives
    }))
    app.mount("#app")
```